# How to view details for error message "Bad Request" for Query API

Tags: vespa

Is there a way to see error details for debugging requests to the Query API?

I am using OkHttpClient to make POST calls to the search endpoint.

I am getting the following error message:

```
Bad Request
```

However, there are no other details in the error message returned by Vespa for trying to debug the error.

I also tried using the vespa-logfmt CLI tool, but there were no other error messages on in the server logs indicating what went wrong with the request.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I was able to figure this out on my own. It ended up being an issue with OkHttp rather than Vespa.

I was using Response.message, but I needed to actually use Response.body().string() to see the full error output.

Apologies for the confusion.